# Generate REST API docs from cucumber tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, cucumber, documentation-generation

There are gems like `rspec_api_documentation` and others which allow you to create API docs for your application directly from working RSpec test code.

My application uses cucumber for testing, exclusively. Is there a way to generate such documentation from cucumber steps/scenarios?

Comment: There was some gem that generated swagger docs from scenarios, not sure it will work for you tho as I think you have to write the scenarios in a certain way.

Comment: That would be fine with me as long as I can leverage my existing steps (to setup test data etc.). Do you recall the name of the gem, @NickM? I can't find it...